# Where can I find the official documentation about how to build VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an official tutorial on how to build your own version of Visual Studio Code?
I already searched on the official GitHub page.
and I searched on Google/Bing.
and I searched on YouTube too. Nothing there.

Comment: What do you mean by "your own version"? Just building from source?

Comment: note to reviewers that [requests for official documentation are on-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417732/11107541). I see that someone has voted to close this as being an off-topic resource recommendation request, which think is wrong.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes  i mean building it from source.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you're looking for is at

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#prerequisites
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#build-and-run

You may also find https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60#issuecomment-161792005 helpful.

I've just archived these pages on web.archive.org just in case.